# Angular 2 and Ionic 2 with Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio, ionic2

So, this may be a stupid question, and if so I do apologize in advance. But I can't seem to find any documentation on this anywhere at all. My goal is to create an Angular 2 project, with Ionic 2 within Visual Studio, but I do not want to utilize any .NET framework. Everything I seem to find either utilizes the .NET framework, or works completely outside of Visual Studio within a separate IDE and utilizing command line tools, as well as node.js and npm. I'm just curious if this was possible to do, or if node.js/npm is the preferred manner of doing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use visual studios code for your IDE. It is the light weight version of visual studios. It also runs on all OS. After that install all your global projects from command line like ionic, ionic CLI, nodejs. I install nodejs because it automatically installs NPM. Then inside VS code you can open the integrated terminal and use the ionic CLI to create a project skeleton and get started. The whole process is very easy and quick. To answer your final question, NPM is the easiest and probably the most documented way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

> utilizing command line tools, as well as node.js and npm

I'm really curious to know how can you build Ionic app without node. You must use Node.

> if node.js/npm is the preferred manner of doing things?

Absolutely YES. If you want,instead of npm, you can use other package manager like yarn.

You can still use the Visual Studio as the IDE if it is your preferred IDE. Even Visual studio has a GUI process to ease the process of building the node app, It still use Node under the hood.